# How to set redux initial State with api call in react with functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using redux in react with typescript. Currently, I am setting my redux initial state via an external JSON file but now I want to set my initial state using API. can I directly create a function in the reducer and create an API call in it or is there any other way to achieve it.

Here is my reducer code:

```
type employee = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type department = {
 [department: string]: employee[]
}
```

right now I am setting initialState via an external file like below:

```
const initial = require("./data.json");
```

I am using this simply in a slice:

```
const departmentSlice = createSlice ({
    name: 'employee',
    initialState: initial,
    reducer: {

    }

})
```

now I want to set initialState via an API call like below:

```
const initial = () => {
  fetch('url').then((response) => {
    return response.json();

  }).catch((error) => {
    throw new Error(error);
  });
}
```

and then set it in initailState.

```
initialState: initial();
```

I am getting this Error:

```
Error: Reducer "employee" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state.
```

Comment: Why do you want to have data in initial state? Can't you just use empty array in initial state and then fetch the data whenever component mounts?

Comment: I want data immediately before the components rendered

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `createSlice` method is synchronous, and your `fetch` method is async. This means when your slice is created, the `fetch` method doesn't complete yet. So you can't do this. You have to define an initially empty state, for example:

`initialState: {data: [], loading: true}`

Because you have a loading variable, you can show a spinner for your user, and when the `fetch` arrives, then you can change this variable back to `false`, and you can populate the `data` at the same time.

Other options can be: state hydration, but this is a more complex case when you don't have access on the backend side.

Note: Your first case is works with JSON, because the JSON import happens before the state initialization.

Comment: for that first, I have to create a intialState property and then set that data in it from which component I have to use the data ?

Comment: For example, yes. But do this with redux actions. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#examples